# Что такое XSD ? с чем его едят?

Tags: java, xsd

Ментор подсказал разбить мой проект на три модуля. Первый это DAO, второй - API(XSD), третий - WEB(service,controller). Первые два - все ясно. Но что такое XSD, и зачем он нужен, и как его использовать я не знаю? А ментор очень поверхностно рассказал, ничего толком не объяснив.

Comment: `XSD` - Xml schema definition, язык описания структуры `xml` документа.

Comment: @hotfix Спасибо на этом уровне я и сам смог "нагуглить". меня больше интересует где и как применяется, в моем случае!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас XSD упоминается в контексте API. Вероятно, ваш ментор имел в виду, что сервис должен в виде XSD предоставлять информацию о формате сообщений, которыми можно с ним обмениваться.

Например, имеется XML вида:

```xml
<data>
    <field1>abc</field1>
    <field2>1<field2>
</data>
```

Можно предположить, что элемент `field1` имеет тип string (строка). Но какого типа `field2`? Строка или число? Если число, то целое или вещественное, знаковое или беззнаковое? Из самого сообщения это нельзя определить. Вся эта и другая информация содержится в XSD.

Конечно, правильно это называется Xml Schema. А xsd - это расширение файлов этого формата.

Более того, существует множество других схем, описывающих форматы передачи данных и способы взаимодействия между сервисом и клиентом. В частности, WSDL, WADL, SOAP и другие. В них описываются не только типы данных, но и методы, которые может выполнять сервис и прочее. Часто их называют просто схемами, а отсюда и некоторая путаница с XSD.

По этим схемам может автоматически генерироваться набор классов (DTO/POJO) на используемом языке программирования, будь то Java или любой другой. А также код самого клиента, сразу содержащий методы для обращения к сервису. Это очень удобно, но, к сожалению, имеется слишком много стандартов таких схем и разные производители ПО поддерживают разные из них.

Comment: То есть Xml Schema это формат обмена информации между клиентом и сервером. Если я правильно понял что то похожее на JSON? Или я чего-то не так понял?

Comment: @Виктор - JSON и XML - это _данные_. Схема - это _описание_ данных, _формат_ данных.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего имелось ввиду разработать API обмена информацией посредством передачи XML структуры.

Т.е. по факту, чтобы взаимодействовать с Вашим сервисом(по идее это - back-end) - то надо посредством POST/GET и пр. запросов посылать вам XML(к примеру).

Ну и "отвечать" вас сервис должен посредством того же формата, к примеру.

Таким модулем может быть набор классов(с аннотациями), которые приходят вам в виде текста, преобразовываются на контроллере в объект. Ну и обратно от объекта в текст вида XML.

Comment: А с помощью XSD, скорее всего, проверяется валидный файл XML или нет (верна ли структура файла).

Comment: Верно! Как поступают популярные frameworks типа Spring. XML - для использования/конфигурации, XSD схемы - для валидации этих самих XML

Comment: То есть Xml Schema это формат обмена информации между клиентом и сервером. Если я правильно понял что то похожее на JSON? Или я чего-то не так понял?